# How can I change my browser screen size to custom size?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi I am in a process in developing responsive webpage using media queries.

Here I need to check for many devices like smartphones, tablets with different min and max width.

**For example :**

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
   @media only screen 
   and (min-device-width : 320px) 
   and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
       }

  /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
   @media only screen 
   and (min-width : 1224px) {
     /* Styles */
    }
```

Here as you can see, I need to check for different widths.

So what I am looking for is, can I find any option in browser where I can just give custom minimum and maximum width, so I can just put my design in that width and arrange as per my need ?

Comment: There's a ton of plugins for that, did you google anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [responsivetest.net](http://responsivetest.net) (work with your local projects too), or download it from [github](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/responsivetest)

Answer (score 2):

using Chrome, you can go under inspect element ctrl+shift+I
then on the bottom right gear button, under ovverides menu, you can enable many test values, from device metrics, to the emulation of css media (screen, print) and so on.

[link to explanation on google.](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation?hl=it)

Answer (score 0):

I test my sites using [screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/)

Comment: that sounds good. But what if my site is still in development phase that is in localhost??

Comment: Try Chrome's Responsive Inspector plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

And use **ripple**

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Firefox have a [Responsive Design View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) built in. On Windows the hotkey is `Ctrl + Shift + M`, or visit the Firefox Menu > Web Developer > Responsive Design View.

In Internet Explorer, you can press `F12` to bring up the developer tools, then visit Tools > Resize and either choose a window size, or enter a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a JavaScript function that executes in the body tags onload event that check for the screen width and size using jQuery's built in functions: width() and height() to check the size of the body element.

Then using if statements you can load different style sheets with this jQuery function.

Example

```
$("body").load(function() { $("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "style2.css"}); });
```

I haven't tested it but it should do the trick.